# How to derive an ontology from a set of triples

Tags: sparql, ontology, triplestore

A problem that comes up a lot when looking at triplified data (data that was generated from RDB and a mapper automatically generated a set of prefixes that canonically reflected the original relational schema) is how to understand that data's hierarchy.

Is it possible to generate the present ontology structure from a set of triples that I have?

I have tried listing all predicates, which produces a flat list of prefixes, but after that, I'm not sure how to identify how all of those predicates relate to each other in a meaningful and repeatable way.

Comment: I think this is probably too broad and open-ended as stated.  Can you show an example of the type of data that you've got, and what type of result you'd like to get?

Comment: Let's just say, for the sake of discussion, that my dataset is dbpedia, and I have no idea what the onology is that governs dbpedia's data. that is a very real-life situation that I encounter constantly. if that is too large, then LinkedMDB could be another example dataset

Comment: It's probably not an exact duplicate, but you might find [Check if an underlying representation is OWL or RDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19822995/1281433) useful.  It describes how you could select the triples that use owl:, rdf:, and rdfs: vocabulary, and thereby "recreate" the ontologies used by the dataset (assuming that the ontology axioms are included in the dataset).