# Extract schema from rdf/xml

Tags: rdf, rdfs, tdb

I am making use of a tool called as FRED (http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred) , which generates the RDF/XML for the given natural language text. But that tool is making use its own predefined schema and also the namespaces. There is no way for the user to give their own schema for the tool.

Whatever the RDF/XML data, which I have got from that tool is fed to Triple Data Store using Apache JENA library. Is it possible to extract the Schema like class properties, objects and Data Properties from the data present in the TDB (Triple DataBase) Store?

Basically I want to get the Schema which is being used by the tool, so that it helps for me to generate the SPARQL from the natural language based on the Schema.

Comment: You might find [Extract ontology / schema for a given SPARQL endpoint / data set](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/25696/extract-ontology-schema-for-a-given-sparql-endpoint-data-set) and [Check if an underlying representation is OWL or RDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19822995/1281433) useful.

Comment: In particular, I think that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19863127/1281433) to the second of those questions may do what you're looking for, if the property and class declarations are present in the data.