# Ontologies with ABox assertions

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I want any ontology with ABox data to test my project.

I came with ABox
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~oktie/linkedmdb/

but I didn't find its ontology, could you help me please?

basically i need to have the ontology with ABox to import to protege and then add some annotation to that ontology.

#### Hint

If you have another Ontology with its rdf dump, that would be appreciated too

#### Update

it sounds like linkedmbd doens't have a corresponding ontology.

I would appreciate if you can give me any ontology with its ABox to import to protege please

#### Update

this is another ontology but without ABox and unfortunately, it sounds like impossible to find any contact us to contact them

#### Update

Unfortunately, this website http://dbtune.org/ never has an ABox.

Comment: re. LinkedMDB ontology (or the lack of it) see http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/21378/linkedmdb-ontology

Comment: @CaptSolo I've already seen that question, and that is why I updated my question adding this infomration.

Comment: @CaptSolo I'd appreciate any kind of rdf with the corresponding ontology, just for testing purposes

Comment: You could try extracting all the data that specifies the ontology, if it's in the data.  There's an example around here somewhere...

Comment: Yes... have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822995/check-if-an-underlying-representation-is-owl-or-rdfs/19863127#19863127, as well as some of the other links from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572853/extract-schema-from-rdf-xml.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i really need something ready, i searched the whole web, it is a shame how all the links are broken, and no one cares, i've been contacting http://dbtune.org/ for three months to solve at least one link to a rdf dump or sparql end point, they keep saying today and tomorrow we fix, and no one did anything

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i just got a question, is it really that no one is using (and will use) semantic web, that is why you can't even find *even one* rdf dump with its corresponding ontology though Tim Bernelse said that linked open data is the next revolution, while i see linked open data is being used just in Bernelse's laptop :)

Comment: Who is Tim Bernelse? And it's not true that nobody is using Semantic Web technologies! The are enough datasets out there, see datahub.io for instance. And there is usually no need to provide the schema in a separate OWL file. Moreover, it's not clear what kind of data you, especially in terms of size and language expressivity. What about DBpedia? Or MusicBrainz, or...

Comment: @AniaDavid "Semantic Web" is really a misnomer;  the point is technology and data representations that are extensible, reusable, and flexible.  Formal ontologies are great, but part of the beauty of "the Semantic Web" is that I can do a quick one off like `<http://stackoverflow.com/users/5883971/ania-david> <http://stackoverflow.com/vocab/posted> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/36034839/1281433>` and have *structured* data that lots of tools can work with. RDF is a very simple data model and doesn't require any sort of schema or ontology;  why would you expect that one always exists?

Comment: If you want a *very* simple "schema" for the LinkedMDB data, why not run some queries like `select ?property ?class where { { ?s ?property ?o } union { ?i a ?class } }`? With a construct query, you can turn that into an RDFS schema document really quickly:  `construct { ?class a rdfs:Class . ?property a rdfs:Property } where { {?s ?property ?o } union {?instance a ?class } }`.

Comment: @AniaDavid And while much of the LinkedMDB page seems to be down (which isn't all that suprising;  it was always sort of an example / "look what we can do" site anyhow), you can see the bit about **"LinkedMDB publishes linked open data using the D2R Server."**  That means that it's generating the data based on a semi-automated mapping from a relational database.  The schema might not even exist in advance.

Comment: @AniaDavid Also, do you mean [Tim Berners-Lee](https://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/)?

Comment: There's also a related thread from about a week ago on the W3C's semantic-web mailing list: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/semantic-web/2016Mar/0036.html asking about LinkedMDB dumps.

Comment: @AKSW please if you can get any triple from datahub, i will be really appreciated, don't let me get started about musicbrains, all their links are broken, and they don't answer all my emails

Comment: @AKSW please search for him, he is the inventor of www and the semantic web :), pretty much he is the reason why we are "speaking" rignt now

Comment: @AniaDavid The person you're talking about is Tim Berners-Lee, not "Tim Bernelse".

Comment: His name is Time Berners-Lee, indeed I know him. Would be good to use the correct name then.

Comment: I apologies, i suck in English but i am trying to learn

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedMDB was powered by a D2R server that takes a relational database and generates RDF from it.  That means that some of the schema may be automatically created and might not exist in advance.  It's not entirely reasonable to expect some kind of schema document to exist *a priori* in all cases.  That said, you've found places where you can download the data dump, and once you've got that, it's really not that hard to generate a workable schema.  I'd use a query like this:

```sql
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

construct {
  ?class a rdfs:Class .
  ?property a rdfs:Property .
}
where {
  { ?instance a ?class }
  union
  { ?s ?property ?o }
}
```

Once you've got that, you can run it on the dump, and you can end up with a schema like the following.  Obviously, there are some things in there that you might want to exclude.  E.g., some of the core RDF and OWL vocabulary are used in there.  LinkedMDB also used some terms from other vocabularies, such as FOAF.  You'll also see that some terms are used as both properties and classes.  That's permissible in RDF, though it might not make for well formed OWL.  If nothing else, though, this should give you a start. For what it's worth, downloading the compressed dump, extracting it, and writing this query took a bit less than ten minutes.  I don't think that's an unreasonable amount of time for getting what's essentially the "API" for a dataset.

```
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_awards_ceremony_id>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_company_film_companyid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/dubbing_performance_dubbing_performanceid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_genre>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_character>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_distribution_medium_film_distribution_mediumid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_special_performance_type>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/special_film_performance_type_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/filmid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_job_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/cinematographer_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/link_target>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/dubbing_performance_language>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_costume_designer>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/special_film_performance_type>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crewmember>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/type_of_film_cut>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_festival_film_festivalid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_awards_ceremony_film_awards_ceremonyid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/actor_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_cut>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/director_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/linkage_run>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/music_contributor_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_system_jurisdiction>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/linkage_score>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/initial_release_date>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/cinematographer>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/linkage_date>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/rating>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_type_personal_film_appearance_typeid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_type_of_appearance>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_critic_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_capital>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_minimum_unaccompanied_age>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_subject_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_format>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_costume_designer_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/dubbing_performance_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crew_gig_film_crew_gigid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_performanceid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/actor>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/costume_designer>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_id>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_film_rating_system>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_collection>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/sequel>
        a       rdfs:Property .

rdfs:SeeAlso  a  rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_collection_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_story_contributor_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/editor_editorid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#subject>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_location_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_system_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_theorist_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/producer_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/genre>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/production_company_production_companyid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/relatedBook>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/language>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_iso_alpha3>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crew_role>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_note>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_awards_ceremony_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/producer_producerid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_cut_note>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://dbpedia.org/property/hasPhotoCollection>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/music_contributor>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://purl.org/dc/terms/date>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_distribution_medium>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/linkage_method>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_languages>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/dubbing_performance_film>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/crewmember>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_story_contributor>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/editor_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/writer>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crewmember_film_crewmemberid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/made>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_system>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_cut_film_cutid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/crew_gig_film>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_critic>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/producer>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/link_type>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_genre_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_part>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_person>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_population>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_country>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_awards_ceremony>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://purl.org/dc/terms/title>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/dubbing_performance>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_actor>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/dubbing_performance_character>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_format_film_formatid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_job>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/actor_actorid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_location>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_character_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/director>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crew_gig_id>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crewmember_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/production_company>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/dubbing_performance_actor>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_genre_film_genreid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/minor_film_genre_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/minor_film_genre>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_series_film_seriesid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_job_film_jobid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_subject>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_format_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/performance_film>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_location_film_locationid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/special_film_performance_type_special_film_performance_typeid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_content_ratingid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_festival>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_costume_designer_film_costume_designerid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/editor>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_release_region>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_subject_film_subjectid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_company>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/director_directorid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/runtime>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_critic_film_criticid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/link_source>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_company_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_character_film_characterid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/music_contributor_music_contributorid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/writer_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/minor_film_genre_minor_film_genreid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_distribution_medium_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_fips_code>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_film>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_continent>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_currency>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_areaInSqKm>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_iso_numeric>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_type_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/based_near>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_character>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_theorist>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/page>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_personal_film_appearanceid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_series_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/linkid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/cinematographer_cinematographerid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/content_rating_system_content_rating_systemid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance_type>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_festival_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/production_company_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crew_gig_name>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/writer_writerid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/oddlinker/interlink>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_story_contributor_film_story_contributorid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/personal_film_appearance>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_crew_gig>
        a       rdfs:Class .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/story_contributor>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_collection_film_collectionid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_theorist_film_theoristid>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/location>
        a       rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/country_iso_alpha2>
        a       rdfs:Property .

rdfs:label  a   rdfs:Property .

<http://data.linkedmdb.org/movie/film_series>
        a       rdfs:Property , rdfs:Class .
```

Comment: I am trying to check your solution, i am having some problems with running jena without reasoning cababilities, i am trying to solve them and come back to you. thanks in advance

Comment: I am having a problem that fuseki doesn't accept *probably* .nt files, so I asked a question, meanwhile i find a solution, and in order to try your solution, do you know please how can i change *autimatially* the .nt format to .ttl format? (or if you have or know another dataset, it is good as well)

Comment: @AniaDavid This *is* ttl.  And I was using Jena's TDB, and loaded up the data with tdbloader.  I'd be very surprised if Fuseki can't load an N-Triples file though;  it's pretty much the most direct data input format there is for RDF.  But if you **really** want to convert between the two, you can use Jena's rdfcat (it comes with the Jena distribution), but you're talking about files that are several hundred megabytes, and already in a format that Jena can read.   I'd worry more about debugging the process of loading an n-triples file.

Comment: @AniaDavid How are you starting Fuseki anyhow?  I thought the usual way was to create a TDB store and then point Fuseki to it?

Comment: to whom the **This** refer to in your first sentence please? Plus, when I download the file from the side, that I've mentioned in the new question, the said it is `.nt`, and indeep it is `.nt`. Moreover, if you are doing it the same way i want to do it, do you think my confige.ttl is no correct please ?

Comment: I start fuseki by `sh start.sh` on my mac os system, I created a folder on my fuseki directory, in order to create a TDB  store

Comment: @AniaDavid Sorry, when I said "this" I meant the schema that I provided.  You meant the data dump.  Sorry about that.  But anyhow, as to how I loaded the data: I did (roughly) `tdbloader --loc /tmp/linkedmdb dump.nt` to create the tdb store, and then ran my queries with `tdbquery --query query.rq --loc /tmp/linkedmdb`.  But when you start Fuseki, you can [just use the --loc command line parameter](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-run.html) to specify the TDB store (e.g., see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17012988/1281433).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Here the questions is what people consider to be contained in a schema. The query just returns a set of classes and properties, but no relationships between, i.e. axioms forming a class or property hierarchy or telling something about domain and range of a property. But as I said, it depends on what people want to be in a schema. From my point of view, and you'll probably agree it contains the terminological data. Therefore you could forward to one of your other great SPARQL examples, where you also retrieved all TBox axioms.

Comment: According to the use case of loading it into Protege, I'm not sure if this works with pure RDFS entities instead of OWL entities.

Comment: @AKSW I included links to some of those in the comments on the question.  But I doubt that they exist in this case.  LinkedMDB is based on a D2R server, so the data is generated automatically from a relational database.  I'd expect that that means there's no *a priori* schema that exists, and the there's probably not much in the way of hierarchy or axiomatic constraints.

Comment: @AKSW No, I don't expect that this will work with Protege.  But Protege is for OWL ontologies, and I don't see any reason yet to expect that the LinkedMDB is described by an OWL ontology.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I did this `./fuseki-server --loc ProposalData/linkedmdb-latest-dump.nt /linkedmdb` and I got this error `ERROR Exception in initialization: caught: Existing file: /usr/local/apache-jena-fuseki-2.0.0/ProposalData/linkedmdb-latest-dump.nt` any clue please? moreover, i understand that even your solution might not reproduce the same ontology to be imported in protege, and i am in hurry, do you think i should keep looking for an ontology with rdf dump? ( i am just afraid now to start with jena poblems and when i solve them, i don't get what i wanted in the first place)

Comment: @AniaDavid The --loc parameter isn't for the data file, it's for the TDB store location.  Like I said in my earlier comment, I created a TDB store **first** using `tdbloader` (though I think that `tdbloader2` is preferred now).  After that, you'd launch Fuseki with a --loc parameter pointing to the (already created) TDB store.  I think the examples that I linked to were pretty clear about that.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i don't have tdbloader2 comand, okay i am so bad i know, i will keep trying alone, i hate myself. thanks for everything, when i can upload the data, i will try your solution

Answer (score 1):

LinkedMdb is generated automatically from a relational data. That is, it has some rdfs properties like range and domain, but it does not have a meaningful type and subclass hierarchy. Also it does not have any value restriction etc.

I suggest to use protege's sample ontologies. For example wine ontology has both schema level info and some accompanying instances. Here is the address --> http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/wine/wine.owl

Also you probably can find other useful onotlogies in their library -->
http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege_Ontology_Library

Comment: the for the second link you provide, i already tried them all, and either the links don't work, or they just ontologies without rdf dump. However, i like the first link about wine, but it is just ontology (schema) please do you know any rdf dump for it?

Comment: How would the pizza or wine ontologies help in making sense of the LinkedMDB data dump?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Oh now i see, it sounds like i wasn't clear in my quesiton, I am asking about **any** ontology with its rdf dump. i searched online i found linkedmdb so i asked about it, but i also said that i am open for any other ontology with its rdf dump. i am sorry i wasn't clear.

Comment: it sounds like "Bahar" got me and he provided a one for wine, thanks him i just need the rdf dump now (the one with read instances)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor to be honest, this sentence `How would the pizza or wine ontologies help in making sense of the LinkedMDB data dump` makes me laugh again.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor to put you in the full picture, as you already know, i am working on a recommender system that users an ontology, it is supposed to work with any ontology, that is why i need any ontology (schema) where i can run my system against, and they i want the rdf dump (the real instances) that i can suggest to the user.

Comment: @AniaDavid "Oh now i see, it sounds like i wasn't clear in my quesiton, I am asking about any ontology with its rdf dump."  No, the title of the question is **where can I find the linkedmdb ontology**.  Please note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "  I'm pretty sure the question is out of the scope for Stack Overflow now.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you are right, it is out of the scope, shall i delete it? **but i indeed need any ontology with its dump rdf**

Comment: @AniaDavid I'm not sure what you mean by "its dump rdf".  While some ontologies may include some instance data, the point of reusable ontologies is precisely that they are reusable and *don't* contain much instance data.  E.g., the FOAF vocabulary has a bunch of vocabulary for describing people and organizations, but it doesn't include descriptions of any actual people.  Instead, people *use* FOAF vocabulary when they're creating their own data.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor okay execuse me for using wrong description, but again it is my problem in using English. I will try again. Look i am building a semantic recommender that is *supposed** to work with any ontology. I developed an ontology so in order to allow any other ontology to be recommended, i will annotate it with my ontology. now the purpose is to recommend instances to users according to things that have linked in the past. so i need data with actual instances. for instances, i need the movie ontology that i will anotate it (joint it) with my ontology, but i also (continue in next comment)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor but i also need actual movies instances in order to recommend them to the user. (these instance i call rdf dump) i am not sure if i make sence now. i hope you got me, othewise, i can write more

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor for instance, i like the wine.owl ontology, it is easy to understand to me, and it is small, so if there is just some instances (rdf dump), some real instances, some real data that is using this ontology, so if i know that you like red wine made in Milano, i suggest you another red wine made from the same grapes but roman one, with the same percentage of alcohol. Another example is if i know that you like "the godfather", (a movie instance), i suggest you the devil's advocate ( a movie instance), these instances come from rdf dump, while the movie class comes from the ontology.

Comment: I think most confusing is the term 'RDF dump' which you probably think of as an equivalent expression for instance data. Usually, RDF dump is more the RDF equivalent of some other data format, e.g. relational data. And as @JoshuaTaylor already set, most Linked Data datasets do not provide a separate file (which you call ontology) containing the schema. And again, there are many RDF dataset out there. What about Bio2RDF for instance?

Comment: @AKSW I checked Bio2RDF they have ABox instances, It's good but as you said, they didn't put the schema (or what I called it the Ontology) in order to load it into protege. any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you made the question more generic (rather than about just LinkedMDB):

Here is a number of ontologies along with sample data:

- http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/opdm/

They also have an [interactive SPARQL tutorial](https://github.com/laczoka/sparql-tutorial) that works with these ontologies.

Comment: In the website you mentioned, there is the books Ontology that I like. However, if you click on the ontology, you will find the **auto generated documentation*, the same for **abox** instances. it would be really really great if you can tell me please where can I download them from. Again, it is written explicitly that those pages have been generated automatcially, so there must be files for them.

Comment: True, they don't link to the RDF version of the ontology. You can find it using *content negotiation* - `curl -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" ontology_URI` - as a result you will get this URI: http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/opdm/book.owl

Comment: Instance data page has a link to RDF version at the top (though link text mentions visualization).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers and comments have pointed out what is required for the question as is. I'm adding this as a separate response as the comment lists are already very long, and this would get lost.

The ORE competition compares reasoner performances on a corpus of ontologies that include large ontologies with big aboxes - i.e., instances. It might be useful for your purposes.

http://mowlrepo.cs.manchester.ac.uk/datasets/ore-2015-reasoner-competition-dataset/

Comment: Kindly do you mean I should download this file https://zenodo.org/record/18578#.Vup-dBKLSqA ? and that file contains both the owl and the a box instances ?

Comment: Yes, the ontologies contain both abox and tbox